Foreign equity call struck in foreign currency, expressed in domestic currency
A foreign equity call, struck in foreign currency, i.e. an option to buy one unit of the foreign equity at the strike price of K units of the foreign currency. The value of this claim at the date of expiration is, expressed in the foreign currency, given by
$$Z_f = max [S_f (T) - K,0 ]$$
Expressed in terms of the domestic currency the value of the claim at T is
$$Z_d = X(T) max [S_f (T) - K,0 ]$$
What is the time no-arbitrage price of the payoff $Z_d$? My first approach is to calculate these two terms  $X(T) \cdot S_f (T)$ and $X(T) \cdot K$ separately to derive it's risk neutral dynamics. In this term $X(T) \cdot K$, the strike price $K$ is a constant so what should we do here?

There are 2 ways of doing it.
First, as you suggested (complicated) as a 2-D domestic payoff.
Basically $N_d(0) E^d \left [ \frac{X(T) (S(T) - K)^+}{N_d(T)} \right ]$
which is a (non trivial) 2-D integral.
Alternatively, the easy way is to convert the foreign price at the 0 exchange rate
$X(0) N_f(0) E^f \left [ \frac{(S(T) - K)^+}{N_f(T)} \right ]$
(it goes without saying that the dynamics of everything have to be adjusted to the correct numeraire)
